# mySQL : Sort ID by a given string of ID ? (Building breadcrumbs for hierarchical-data)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, hierarchical-data

I'm building a website with PHP & mySQL.
In my application, the categories of products are stored as hierarchy in DB.
I followed the approach of "Materialized path" (aka "Flat table Model") & created a table like this :

[image]

Suppose I want to build a breadcrumb for items in category FLASH (category_id=8) :

**ELECTRONICS -> PORTABLE ELECTRONICS -> MP3 PLAYERS -> FLASH**

I wonder if I could get the line of ancestry from 'FLASH' IN CORRECT ORDER by this query:

```
Select * from category where category_ID in (1,6,7,8) ORDER BY '1,6,7,8'
```

What can be the correct replacement for :

```
ORDER BY '1,6,7,8'
```

? Thanks for all suggestions !

Comment: `category_ID in (1,6,7,8) ORDER BY category_ID` might mean you get the results in the order (1,6,7,8). But, same query with `category_ID in (1,8,7,6) ORDER BY category_ID` will return the results in wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer my own !

```
SELECT * 
FROM category
WHERE category_ID
IN ( 1, 6, 7, 8 ) 
ORDER BY category_ID =1 DESC , category_ID =8 DESC , category_ID =7 DESC , category_ID =6 DESC
```

The SQL string above can help me to sort ID by any predefined order : 1-6-7-8 or 1-8-7-6 or  6-1-8-7 or any thing else !

Answer (score 1):

A way more elegant and efficient way to achieve this would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `category_ID` IN(1,6,7,8) ORDER BY Field(`category_ID`,1,6,7,8)
```

Greets,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

I may not be getting the question right, but do you mean this?

```
Select * from category where category_ID in (1,6,7,8) ORDER BY category_id
```

Comment: No, I want the results to be sorted exactly by the order in the parentheses : 1,6,7,8. In other words, If the string was : '8,7,1,6' then the order of the results should be : 8,7,1,6